Vulkan window is not opening
I am following through the tutorial in the vulkan website.
Vulkan tutorial
I went through all the initial setup on arch linux and executing vkcube actually works properly and opens a window with the spinning cube. however, after going through the "Setting up a Makefile" portion of the Development Environment section of the tutorial a vulkan window is supposed to open. My code executes but I dont see any windows.
This is the main.cpp
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main(){
  glfwInit();

  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Vulkan Window", nullptr, nullptr);

  uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
  vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);

  std::cout << extensionCount << "extesions supported\n";

  glm::mat4 matrix;
  glm::vec4 vec;
  auto test = matrix * vec;

  while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glfwPollEvents();
  }

  glfwDestroyWindow(window);

  glfwTerminate();

  return 0;
}


and here is the Makefile
CFLAGS = -std=c++17 -O2
LDFLAGS = -lglfw -lvulkan -ldl -lpthread -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi

VulkanTest: main.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o VulkanTest main.cpp $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: test clean

test: VulkanTest
    ./VulkanTest

clean:
    rm -f VulkanTest


This is what i get after I execute without the window popping up.

./VulkanTest
24extesions supported



I tried going through other tutorials but there were no issues with the setup environment in any of the tutorials i looked at.

If you are using Wayland, see this answer.

Oh thanks. It is using Wayland. I had no idea
